# Wt C++ Json comparison operator does not work

Tags: c++, wt

The code below is written in C++ using WebTool kit for C++. In this [reference document](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Json_1_1Value.html#a741475c334e1093ae3c527755916f237) it is stated that operator== returns bool if the types and values are equal. But the code below always prints "Equal" . I tried with other types like bool but it always enters first block. Are there something wrong with overloaded comparison operator?

```
    #include <Wt/Json/Object>
    #include <Wt/Json/Parser>
    ...

    Json::Object result;
    Json::parse("{\"message\":\"Hello\"}", result);


    if (result.get("message") == Wt::Json::Value("Not Hello")) {
      std::cout << "Equal" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Not Equal" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Wt: http://redmine.emweb.be/issues/5339